# Connect to MongoDB with self-signed certificate from EVE

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, eve

MongoDB uses self-signed certificate. I want to setup service on EVE to work with it. I searched documentation and SO but found only information how to use self-signed cert to access EVE itself. What should I do to connect to MongoDB from EVE with self-signed certificate?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by passing required parameters (ssl, ssl_ca_certs, etc) to MongoClient via MONGO_OPTIONS setting.